# Amount of arrays with unique numbers

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have been wondering if there is any better solution of this problem:
Let's assume that there are **n containers** (they might not have the same length). In each of them we have some numbers. What is the amount of n-length arrays that are created by taking one element from every container? **Those numbers in the newly formed arrays must be unique** (e.g. (2,3,3) can not be created but (2,4,3) can).
Here is an exaple:

n=3

c1=(1,6,7)

c2=(1,6,7)

c3=(6,7)

The correct answer is 4, because we can create those four arrays: (1,6,7), (1,7,6), (6,1,7), (6,7,1).

Edit: None of the n containers contain duplicates and all the elements in the new arrays must have the same order as the order of the containers they belong to.

**So my question is: Is there any better way to calculate the number of those arrays than just by generating every single possibility and checking if it has no repetitions?**

Comment: You can remove duplicates from all 3 arrays, you can simply create permutations, you don't have to worry about there being a duplicate.

Comment: @LinuxGeek If I removed all the duplicates I would have just the first array and the answer would be 3, but I guess that I didn't understand your idea. Could you clarify what do you mean? How would it work on the example mentioned above?

Comment: @display, I think that `Linux` means to remove duplicates *within* the arrays, not between them. So `c1 = (1, 1, 3, 4)` becomes `c1 = (1, 3, 4)`. I agree that it's a useful step, but it doesn't completely solve the problem either.

Comment: Why isn't `(7,6,1)` a valid output but `(6,7,1)` is?

Comment: @Elliott I Forgot to say that there can't be any duplicates inside of a container.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Oh, another mistake, all the elements in the new arrays must have the same order as the order of the containers they belong to.

Comment: It is still wrong. How is (1,7,6) possible? You don't preserve 6's position.

Comment: @snr I do. 6 has index 3 in the new array and it is taken from the 3rd container. I just iterate through all the containers and take 1 number from each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to generate each possibility and *then* check whether or not it has repetitions - you can do that *before* adding the would-be duplicate element, saving a lot of wasted work further down the line. But yes, given the requirement that

> all the elements in the new arrays must have the same order as the
> order of the containers they belong to

you cannot simply count permutations, or combinations of m-over-n, which would have been much quicker (as there is a closed formula for those).

Therefore, the optimal algorithm is probably to use a backtracking approach with a set to avoid duplicates while building partial answers, and count the number of valid answers found.

The problem looks somewhat like counting possible answers to a 1-dimensional sudoku: choose one element each from each region, ensuring no duplicates. For many cases, there may be 0 answers - imagine `n=4, c=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,1],[2,3]]`. For example, if are less than `k` unique elements for a subset of `k` containers, no answer is possible.